# Asymptotics and Related Properties

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I have a rather general question:  If there are two integer sequences such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}A(n)/n=\lim_{n\to\infty}B(n)/n=c$$ is there anything else that can be said about them necessarily?  That is, are there properties that must, or more weakly one should expect to also hold for both sequences?

Comment: $A(n)=O(n), \ B(n)=O(n)$ for example?

Comment: Can't say much if $c=0$. But otherwise we know the long run ratio of $A(n)$ and $B(n)$.

Comment: I had in mind the case where c is some positive non-integer value like 3/2 so the long run ratio is nice, though not quite what I hoped might exist.

Comment: I don't get it: `A(n)=B(n)=cn` for every `n`, no?

Comment: Not quite, but it was my sloppy notation - n is approaching infinity here so such manipulation would be impossible.  Limits should precede each recursive term.

Comment: Then you might want to rephrase in a less "sloppy" way.

Comment: Edited as requested.

Comment: Maybe $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{A(n)}{B(n)} = 1$?

Comment: That is interesting, but I was hoping there might be examples of sequences where we can say something about A(n) examining it separately, then note that both A(n) and B(n) approach 1/2, and consequently derive a fact about B(n) (perhaps that the fact we derived about A(n) is also true for B(n)).  I expect this is unlikely, and I should have been more clear in my initial question so my apologies.